# Play! framework routes. long data type

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, web-development-server

it seems that I have a problem with defining Long variables in *routes*.
this is the line in the *routes* file:

```
GET   /topic/:id                    controllers.Topics.show(id: Long)
```

and this is the method to handle this route:

```
public static Result show(long id) {
   // handle request here...
}
```

what I get is error 324:

> Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.

I think the problem is with the *Long* data type because with *Int* it works like a charm.
what is the tweak to make it work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use the `Long` object instead of the `long` primary type in your action:

```
public static Result show(Long id) {
   // handle request here...
}
```